# Express.js: Passport.ensureAuthenticated() is always true

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

I am a bit confused with following situation. I am using passport JS with google auth to login into my website. After that I tried to secure a route behind login and it is always return true.

I know it is a lot of code and I am asking for a lot of time for somebody to check this out, but I am really at the loss here and I am thinking I am missing something really obvious :(

Thank you ahead for your time!

Here is related code server `index.js` code. Nothing out of the ordinary in my opinion

```
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
if (env === 'development') dotenv.config();

import express from 'express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import compression from 'compression';
import cookieParser from 'cookie-parser';
import methodOverride from 'method-override';

// IMPORT AUTH DEFAULT FUNCTION, THIS DEFINES THE STRATEGY
import auth from './middleware/auth';

import routes from './routes';
import database from './database';
import models from './models';

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000,
      app  = express(),
      router = express.Router(),
      sequelize = database();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(compression());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(methodOverride());

models(sequelize).then(models => {
  // CALL AUTH DEFAULT FUNCTION, THIS SHOULD SET WHOLE STORY IN MOTION
  auth(app);
  routes(app);
  app.listen(PORT);
});
```

Here is my routes file, I am declaring router and at the end saying that app should use it, I am actually suspecting this might be the issue, but not sure how to properly test this (unless I ditch router and just use `app.use` instead of `router.use`)

```
import express from 'express';
import path from 'path';
import serveStatic from 'serve-static';

// IMPORT JUST THE ensureAuthenticated MIDDLEWARE
import {ensureAuthenticated} from '../middleware/auth';
import * as tasks from './tasks';

const router = express.Router(),
      root   = path.join(__dirname, '..');

export default function (app) {
  const frontendPublicPath = path.join(root, '..', 'frontend', 'build');

  router.use('/', serveStatic(frontendPublicPath));

  // TRY TO LOCK THIS ROUTE BEHIND AUTH
  router.use('/admin/dosomething', ensureAuthenticated, task.doSomething);

  router.use('*', serveStatic(frontendPublicPath));
  app.use('/', router);
};
```

At the end here is the auth file which sets everything up

```
import passport from 'passport';
import expressSession from 'express-session';
import connectPgSimple from 'connect-pg-simple';
import googleAuth from 'passport-google-oauth';

import {models} from '../models/index';

const googleStrategy = googleAuth.OAuth2Strategy;

function setupPassport() {
  passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {done(null, user);});
  passport.deserializeUser((obj, done) => {done(null, obj);});

  passport.use(new googleStrategy({ clientID: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID, clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET, callbackURL:  process.env.GOOGLE_CALLBACK_URL
    }, function (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
      process.nextTick(() => {
        models.Users.login(profile).then((userRecord) => {
          if (!userRecord.err) return done(null, userRecord);
          else return done(userRecord.err, null);
        });
      });
    }
  ));
}


/* Should be able to use this on whole app level if wanted, in that case
   allowedGuestRoutes would kick in to allow certain routes always to pass
   In example: app.use(ensureAuthenticated) !! NOT USED IN THIS CASE

   Also can be used on single routes by passing it as middleware
   In example: router.use('/admin/dosomething', 
                          ensureAuthenticated, 
                          task.doSomething);

   'root' route  - should be able to access route to get homepage served
   'dist' folder - should be able to access css / js and assets
   'auth' routes - should be able to access route to be able to login */

export function ensureAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
  const allowedGuestRoutes = ['/auth/','/api/'];
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    // I ALWAYS END UP HERE SINCE THIS IF CASE IS ALWAYS TRUE <-----------
    return next();
  } else {
    /* Don't reject, check if this route is public */
    let publicRoute = false;
    if (req.url === '/') {
      publicRoute = true;
      return next();
    }
    allowedGuestRoutes.forEach(guestRoute => {
      if (req.url.indexOf(guestRoute) === 0) {
        publicRoute = true;
        return next();
      }
    });
    if (!publicRoute) {
      logger.error(req, 'Not allowed to access route');
      res.redirect('/');
    }
  }
}

export default function (app) {
  const pgSession       = connectPgSimple(expressSession),
        cookieAge       = 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
        sessionSettings = { 
          store: new pgSession({conString: process.env.DATABASE_URL,tableName: 'Sessions'}),
          secret: process.env.DATABASE_SECRET,
          resave: false,
          saveUninitialized: false,
          cookie: {maxAge: cookieAge}
        };

  app.use(expressSession(sessionSettings));
  setupPassport();
  app.use(passport.initialize());
  app.use(passport.session());
  //app.use(ensureAuthenticated);

  app.get('/auth/google', passport.authenticate('google', {scope: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email']}), (req, res) => {
    // this is being handled by google guys, they are smarter
  });

  app.use('/auth/google/callback', passport.authenticate('google', {failureRedirect: '/'}), (req, res) => {
    res.locals.user = req.user;
    if (req.cookies.loggedIn === undefined) {
      res.cookie('loggedIn', true, {maxAge: cookieAge});
    }
    res.redirect('/');
  });

  // on each request, save user data in res.local so we can use it on views
  app.use((req, res, next) => {
    if (!req.user) {
      req.user = {};
    }
    res.locals.user = req.user;
    next();
  });

  app.get('/logout', (req, res) => {
    if (req.user) {
      logger.action(req.user.name + ' logged out', 'gray');
    }
    req.logout();
    res.cookie('loggedIn', '', {expires: new Date(0)});
    res.redirect('/');
  });
};
```

To recap:

- problem is in `auth.js` that `req.isAuthenticated()` is always set to true.
- frontend uses `document.cookie.indexOf('loggedIn=') === -1;` to figure out if it needs to show login or logout button in navbar, works as expected
- if I logout and then go again to login, I will be presented with google window to choose user (or login with google user), so this works as expected as well

So in the end the only thing that is really failing is that `req.isAuthenticated()` can't figure out that user is logged out. Any help or pointers would be highly appreciated!